# How to get image url from config.json file in assets and display it in index.html file in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angular, http, frontend

I have an angular project where i have a config file in assets folder

```
{
    "brandConfig": "brand1",
    
    "brand1":
    {"urlPath": "http://192.168.168.60:8081/mantle-services",
        "brandName": "brand1",
        "logoPath": "assets/images/logos/logosemiwhite.svg",
        "logo1": "assets/images/logos/logosemiwhite.svg",
        "logo2": "assets/images/logos/logo.svg",
        "theme":"theme-brand1",
        "defaultLanguage": "en"
        
   },

   "brand2":{
    "urlPath": "http://192.168.168.70:8081/mantle-services",
    "brandName": "brand2",
    "logoPath": "assets/images/logos/brand2-white.png",
    "logo1": "assets/images/logos/bbrand2-only-symbol.png",
    "logo2": "assets/images/logos/logo.svg",
    "theme":"theme-fynhouse",
    "defaultLanguage": "en"
   }
}
```

I need to load the logoPath in index.html file .

this is the body in index.html file:

```
<body>

        <!-- FUSE Splash Screen -->
        <fuse-splash-screen id="fuse-splash-screen">

            <div class="center">

                <div class="logo">
                    <img width="128" src="assets/images/logos/logosemiwhite.svg">
                </div>

                <!-- Material Design Spinner -->
                <div class="spinner-wrapper">
                    <div class="spinner">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <div class="gap"></div>
                            <div class="left">
                                <div class="half-circle"></div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="right">
                                <div class="half-circle"></div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!-- / Material Design Spinner -->

            </div>

        </fuse-splash-screen>
        <!-- / FUSE Splash Screen -->

        <app></app>

    </body>
```

as you can see the image is now hardcoded in index.html

```
<img width="128" src="assets/images/logos/logosemiwhite.svg">
```

any suggestions on how to replace the link here with brand1.logoPath from the above config file placed in assets .
this is the config file (brand-config.json)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I having the same circumstance as yours, following is my solution and the codes you can put under `app.component.ts`:

```
constructor(@Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document;)
{
  const brands = require('../your_path/../config.json');

  let config: string = brands['brandConfig'];
  var brand = brands['config'];

  this._document.getElementById('img_tag_id').setAttribute('src', brand['logoPath']);
}
```

Not sure if this solution can help you.

Comment: and you put this code inside <script> tags in index.html you mean?

Comment: require isn't working inside script tag

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I've updated my answer, hope this helps.